# JS & PHP Interaction

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I've got an input text field for postcode. Based on the postcode that a user enters, a price for shipping is designated with PHP (different post code zones have different shipping costs).

Later in the form, whatever shipping price was designated then needs to be used as part of a JS calculation to get the total.

Here's my PHP:

```
  if ($postcode >= 2000 && <= 2234) {
    $shipping = 55.00;
  } elseif ($postcode >= 2250 && <= 2310) {
    $shipping = 105.00;
  } elseif ($postcode >= 2311 && <= 2359) {
    $shipping = 160.00;   
 }

echo $shipping;
?>
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#postcode').change(function(){
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "shipping.php",
            data: 'shipping=' + $('#postcode').val(),
            success: function(msg){
                $('#shipping').html(msg);
            }

        }); // Ajax Call

    }); //event handler
}); //document.ready
```

So I don't think the data & success of the AJAX call are correct. Basically, I need to get the value of $shipping & then output that to a div (so that the user can see it). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

make an ajax call to a php file, and submit the postcode. The server code should return (echo) the shipping price for the given postcode. Get the response from ajax, which will be shipping price. You can now use this value in your calculations (value should be converted to int or float, because response from ajax is text by default)

Comment: I added my code so far to make it clearer. I understand what you're saying, but not sure what I need to add/change. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code:

```
if ($postcode >= 2000 && <= 2234) {
  $shipping == 55.00;
} elseif ($postcode >= 2250 && <= 2310) {
  $shipping == 105.00;
} elseif ($postcode >= 2311 && <= 2359) {
  $shipping == 160.00;   
}
```

You must use assignment operator (single =), instead of equals operator (==). Example: $shipping == 55.00 becomes $shipping = 55.00

Also, the operand (variable) is missing from second conditions in all the if statements:
Instead of

```
 if ($postcode >= 2000 && <= 2234) {
```

use below:

```
  if ($postcode >= 2000 && $postcode<= 2234) {
```

Comment: Did you look into the Apache error log? (supposing you are using Apache)